# Yii2 urlManager редирект с controller/q/w/... на controller/index

Tags: регулярные-выражения, yii2, redirect, url-manager

Собственно, нужно прописать редирект, где при наличии controllerName в урле(независимо от остальной части урла, вложенности), будет обращение к методу index, контроллера controllerName
Сейчас реализовано так:
'controller:news/action:.+' => 'news/index',
Однако, происходит редирект с "example.com/news/some/path" на "example.com/news?action=news%..." Этого и нужно избежать

Answer (score 0):

Вот так у меня сделано для ссылок на страницу активации вида `mysite.com/activate/<md5 string>`

```php
'rules' => [
            '<controller:activate>/<link:(.+?)' => '<controller>/index',
          ],
```

В контроллере

```pgp
  public function actionIndex($link = null) {
  }
```

Это я к тому, что Вам же нужно передавать в `index` ту самую `остальную часть вложенности` т.е `some/path` поэтому и нужно как-то именовать переменную которая будет передана в `actionIndex` в которой и будет сидеть `some/path`

Поэтому в Вашем случае `rules` будет выглядеть примерно так

```php
'rules' => [
            '<controller:news>/<link:(.+?)' => '<controller>/index',
          ],
```

А в контроллере вот так

```pgp
  public function actionIndex($link = null) {
  }
```

Учтите, что согласно `RFC` обращение к сайту по `URL`-ам `mysite.com/news?<тут что-то>` и `mysite.com/news/<тут что-то>` и даже `mysite.com/news` и `mysite.com/news/` будут считаться разными и соответственно `URL`ы без `/` после `news` под описанное правило не попадут